# Is there a closed form for the number of ways to put up to $k$ chess pieces on a board with $n$ squares?

Tags: combinatorics, closed-form

Given a chess board with $n$ squares, the number of ways $c(n,k)$ to put up to $k$ pairwise distinguishable chess pieces on the board can be described by

$$c(n,k)=nc(n-1,k-1)+c(n,k-1)\quad\hbox{where }c(n,0)=1\hbox{ and }c(0,k)=1$$

where the first term indicates the choice to place the next piece on the board and the second term indicates the choice to leave the next piece off the board.

One can easily see that the second term can be unfolded to yield

$$c(n,k) = 1+n\sum_{i=1}^kc(n-1,i-1)$$

but that's where I couldn't progress anymore. Is there a closed form for $c(n,k)$?

Comment: It appears you are allowing multiple pieces per square.  It also appears that the pieces are in an order and once you don't place a piece you can't place any more.  Is that what you intend?

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm not sure what to make of your comment. I don't allow multiple pieces per square. That's why the square count goes down once I place a piece (that square is excluded for future pieces). I'm also allowing further pieces to be placed if I choose not to place a certain piece (that's why the second term is $c(n,k-1)$.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question properly, you are looking for $\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{n!}{(n-i)!}$, right?

Comment: The fact that you multiply by $n$ at each step says that all the squares are allowed for each piece, including the ones already occupied.  Then in going from $k=0$ to $k=1$ you don't multiply by the number of distinct pieces, so you only allow the first piece to be placed if $k=1$

Comment: @MichaelBiro: that would be correct if you don't get to select the pieces from a collection, as in the second half of my last comment.

Comment: @RossMillikan Note how I pass $n-1$ into the left term, excluding the square I placed the current piece at. In the right term, no piece has been placed, so $n$ is passed down. For your second comment, I do multiply with the number of pieces, that's why the left term is $n\times c(n-1,k-1)$.

Comment: @MichaelBiro I think if you multiply each term with $k\choose i$, then it's correct.

Comment: If you have six different pieces and want to place two, there are fifteen ways to choose the two you will place.  That is nowhere in your calculation.  I see how your $nc(n-1,k-1)$ excludes multiple pieces per square.  In essence, you are choosing the square for the last piece first, then restricting the rest from being there.  It is more usual to place the first piece first.  The recursion then involves $(n-k+1)c(n,k-1)$ because you have already placed $k-1$ pieces and have $n-k+1$ squares left to place the last one.  That way you don't have to change the first index.

Comment: @RossMillikan This is of course in my calculation because I place the pieces in order and in each step, I can decide not to place a piece. I think there is a huge misunderstanding. How do I exclude multiple pieces per square? The intent of the left term is “I want to place the first piece. There are $n$ squares to do so. After that, there are $n-1$ squares left to place the remaining $k-1$ pieces, so the total number is $nc(n-1,k-1)$.” For the right term it's “I do not want to place the first piece, I have $n$ squares to place the remaining $k-1$ pieces so the number is $c(n,k-1)$.”

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm sorry, but I don't see how that reasoning is wrong.

Comment: I don't think it is wrong, but I think it is more complicated than necessary because you need to compute $c$'s with more than one value of the first argument.  When I am computing $c(n,k)$ the first $k-1$ pieces have already been placed, so there are $n-k+1$ squares left for the $k^{th}$ piece.  The advantage is that the first argument of $c$ stays at $n$.  I think it is simpler and will follow more of the texts that way.

Comment: @RossMillikan Your reasoning is not correct: Not all of the preceding $k-1$ might have been placed, $c(n,k)$ computes the amount of way to place all proper and improper subsets of the $k$ pieces on the board, so it's not that easy.

Comment: @MichaelBiro I have confirmed your closed form to be correct. Would you mind posting this as an answer?

Comment: @FUZxxl No problem, did you change your mind about multiplying by $\binom{k}{i}$? Let me know and I can edit if necessary.

Comment: @MichaelBiro No. Your formula is only correct after multiplying by $k\choose i$ because otherwise you don't distinguish what subset with $i$ pieces you choose out of the $k$ pieces available.

Comment: Ok, so that assumes a set of $k$ pieces to be placed and not just that the pieces are distinguishable once placed, right?

Comment: @MichaelBiro Yes. Exactly, that's the intent of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, I noted that this problem was essentially $$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} \frac{n!}{(n-i)!}$$

While not technically closed form, it might help to find some simplifying factorial or binomial identities...

Comment: Wolfram Alpha finds a closed form in terms of the *confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind:* $\sum^k_{i=0}{k\choose i}{n!\over(n-i)!}=(-1)^kU(-k,-k+n+1,-1).$ Though, I don't think this is any more useful.